# Creating a comparator class for Java TreeSet

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

I have created a comparator class for Java's TreeSet function that I wish to use to order messages. This class looks as follows

```
public class MessageSentTimestampComparer
{
/// <summary>
/// IComparer implementation that compares the epoch SentTimestamp and MessageId
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x"></param>
/// <param name="y"></param>
/// <returns></returns>

public int compare(Message x, Message y)
{
    String sentTimestampx = x.getAttributes().get("SentTimestamp");
    String sentTimestampy = y.getAttributes().get("SentTimestamp");

    if((sentTimestampx == null) | (sentTimestampy == null))
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("Unable to compare Messages " +
                "because one of the messages did not have a SentTimestamp" +
                " Attribute");
    }

    Long epochx = Long.valueOf(sentTimestampx);
    Long epochy = Long.valueOf(sentTimestampy);

    int result = epochx.compareTo(epochy);

    if (result != 0)
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        // same SentTimestamp so use the messageId for comparison
        return x.getMessageId().compareTo(y.getMessageId());
    }
}
}
```

But when I attempt to use this class as the comparator Eclipse gives and error and tells me to remove the call. I have been attempting to use the class like this

```
private SortedSet<Message> _set = new TreeSet<Message>(new MessageSentTimestampComparer());
```

I have also attempted to extend the MessageSentTimestampComparer as a comparator with no success. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `MessageSentTimestampComparer` doesn't *implement* [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Try this:

```
public class MessageSentTimestampComparer implements Comparator<Message> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Message x, Message y) {
    return 0;  // do your comparison
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot the difference between implements and extends. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you check the constructor signatue - [`public TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29), the parameter type is [`java.util.Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

So your comparator must implement the `Comparator` interface (for the compiler to not complain) as follows -

```
public class MessageSentTimestampComparer implements Comparator<Message> {
```